# How can I pad matrix in python without using the np.pad() function?

Tags: numpy

I want to take matrix 1 like the one below and pad it with 1 padding so that it looks like matrix 2 or pad it with 2 padding to make it look like matrix 3. I want to do this without using using the np.pad() or any other Numpy function.

Matrix 1

```
| 4 4 |
| 7 2 |
```

Matrix 2 - with padding of 1

```
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 4 4 0 |
| 0 7 2 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 |
```

Matrix 3 - with padding of 2

```
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 5 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 7 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
```

Comment: What have you tried alreay? Is the input a list of lists or an np.array? Do you only want to pad two dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom pad function like so:

**Very late edit:** Do not use this function, use the one below it called `pad2()`.

```
def pad(mat, padding):
    
    dim1 = len(mat)
    dim2 = len(mat[0])

    # new empty matrix of the required size
    new_mat = [
        [0 for i in range(dim1 + padding*2)]
        for j in range(dim2 + padding*2)
    ]

    # "insert" original matix in the empty matrix
    for i in range(dim1):
        for j in range(dim2):
            new_mat[i+padding][j+padding] = mat[i][j]

    return new_mat
```

It might not be the optimal/fastest solution, but this should work fine for regular sized matrices.

---

**Very late edit:**
I tried to use this function on a non square matrix and noticed it threw an `IndexError`. So for future reference here is the corrected version that works for `N x M` matrices (where `N != M`):

```
def pad2(mat, padding, pad_with=0):
    n_rows = len(mat)
    n_cols = len(mat[0])

    # new empty matrix of the required size
    new_mat = [
        [pad_with for col in range(n_cols + padding * 2)]
        for row in range(n_rows + padding * 2)
    ]

    # "insert" original matix in the empty matrix
    for row in range(n_rows):
        for col in range(n_cols):
            new_mat[row + padding][col + padding] = mat[row][col]

    return new_mat
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you so much!